# Is --- Cobol picture valid

Tags: cobol

I'm running some tests on Cobol pictures and wondering if `---` is a valid picture. Am I right in saying that this picture accepts values in the range of -99 through to +99. If it is valid then it is possible for the picture to accept 3 spaces as a value?

For example:

12 would return  12 
1  would return   1

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes `---` is a valid `PICTURE` clause. The variable corresponding to this `PICTURE` will accept assignments of numeric values in the range -99 through to +99. It cannot be assigned non-numerics (space for example). However, if you were to `DISPLAY` this variable after assigning a numeric value to it, leading zeros will be replaced by spaces. Consequently, if you `MOVE ZERO` to this item it will `DISPLAY` only spaces. Attempting to `MOVE SPACES` to this item will result in a compile error (incompatible data types). This last bit may seem a little counter intutive, but remember that this type of `PICTURE` clause implies a `USAGE` of display - basically items defined in this manner are used to 'pretty print' numbers. About the only operations you can preform with `USAGE DISPLAY` items is `MOVE` to or from and `DISPLAY` them.

**EDIT - Response to Comment**

A `PICTURE` of `---X(2)` is invalid. The chart below illustrates combinations and the order that symbols may appear in a `PICTURE` string. Notice that parenthesis are not in the chart. Logically you can replace them with the corresponding number of occurences of the preceding character before reading the string. For example `X(3)` is read as `XXX`. If you really want to parse out a `PICTURE` string properly, you can use this chart to construct a BNF grammar specifically for them.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @NealB. So I take it you can't mix a numeric display like --- and X(2) so you have ---X(2)? Would that be valid? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If this is a numeric picture, it won't accept spaces.